# array of object retrieving data and average

Tags: arrays, function, object, methods

I've just started learning JavaSCript and I have some trouble with this exercise.
I have an array of objects with around 250 object in it. There are multiple movies in it (I pasted only the first 2 movies in the array but the structure is the same):

Create a dramaMoviesRate() function that receives an array as a parameter to get the average rate of all drama movies! Let's see if it is better than the general average.

Again, rounded to 2 decimals!

My logic is: 1)select only the movies that include the string 'Drama', and 2)calculate the average of them.

My problem is: according to the test I should store everything into a function. And secondly, when I try to filter Drama movies I also get other movies that don't contain that string as output.
Please use JS ES5 syntax, thank you.

PS: I MUST USE ONLY THE METHODS I KNOW WHICH ARE:
filter() map() reduce() sort() reverse() slice()

```
let movies = [
  {
    title: "The Shawshank Redemption",
    year: 1994,
    director: "Frank Darabont",
    duration: "2h 22min",
    genre: ["Crime", "Drama"],
    rate: 9.3,
  },
  {
    title: "The Godfather",
    year: 1972,
    director: "Francis Ford Coppola",
    duration: "2h 55min",
    genre: ["Crime", "Drama"],
    rate: 9.2,
  }
]

function howManyDrama(phDrama) {
  const drama = phDrama.filter(function (movie) {
    return (
  movie.genre.includes('Drama')
    );
  });
  return drama;
}   ==>//HERE I DON'T GET THE RIGHT OUTPUT


//console.log(movies)


function dramaMoviesRate(pdrama){
  const average = pdrama.reduce(function(acc, movie){ 
   return acc + movie.rate
   },0);
   return Math.round((average / pdrama.length) * 100) / 100;
}

-----------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 //I also thought to filter my drama movies and then store the //function that has an array as output as argument of my second //function like this:

function howManyDrama(phDrama) {   //thats the fist to filter //drama with incorrect output
  const drama = phDrama.filter(function (movie) { 
    return (
  movie.genre.includes('Drama')
    );
  });
  return drama;
}
  
function dramaMoviesRate(howManyDrama){
  const average = howManyDrama.reduce(function(acc,movie){
  return acc.movie.rate
  },0);
  return Math.round((average / howManyDrama.length) * 100) / 100

}


howManyDrama(movies)

dramaMoviesRate(howManyDrama)
```

Please use ES5 Syntax. Thanks for the patience!

Answer (score 0):

I ran you code. The Drama filter is working correctly. I updated the totaling process to be cleaner. I could not get the reduce method to work correctly, so I used map instead.

Try this code:

```
let movies = [
  {
    title: "The Shawshank Redemption",
    year: 1994,
    director: "Frank Darabont",
    duration: "2h 22min",
    genre: ["Crime", "Drama"],
    rate: 9.3,
  },
  {
    title: "The Godfather",
    year: 1972,
    director: "Francis Ford Coppola",
    duration: "2h 55min",
    genre: ["Crime", "Drama"],
    rate: 9.2,
  },
  {
    title: "Mission Impossible",
    year: 1999,
    director: "zzz",
    duration: "2h 55min",
    genre: ["Action"],
    rate: 7.2,
  }
]

function howManyDrama(phDrama) {
  const drama = phDrama.filter(function (movie) {
    return (
      movie.genre.includes('Drama')
    );
  });
  return drama;
}  


function dramaMoviesRate(pdrama){
  let total = 0
  let result = pdrama.map(x => total += x.rate);
  return total/pdrama.length
}

let m = howManyDrama(movies)
console.log(m)  //correct

let r = dramaMoviesRate(m)
console.log(r)  // correct


// do everything in single function
function dramaRate(movielist) {
  const drama = movielist.filter(function (movie) {
    return (
      movie.genre.includes('Drama')
    );
  });
  let total = 0
  let result = drama.map(x => total += x.rate);
  return total/drama.length
}

console.log(dramaRate(movies))  //single function call
```